# How to cast resultset in rowmapper to an enum?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have my rowmapper like:

```
private static final class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

    User user = new User();

      user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
      user.setUserType( (UserType)rs.getInt("userType")); // ?????

    return user;

}
```

So I am trying to cast the integer value in the db for userType to the enumeration UserType.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cast it?  No, can't be done.

You can call valueOf to get the Enum value from the String, as long as the String is valid.

Answer (score 4):

You can index into `Enum.values()`:

```
user.setUserType( UserType.values()[rs.getInt("userType")] );
```

You might want to put in some error checking. :)